# What options are there to call Lua code within an android project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lua, android-ndk

I want to take [this open-source project](https://github.com/PathOfBuildingCommunity/PathOfBuilding), which is a build calculator for the online game Path of Exile, and port it to an android app. The project, called Path of Building (PoB), is written fully in Lua, and is released as a windows application. I'm not sure to what extent it's possible to simply wrap their lua code and just show it in an activity, but, since the project gets updated often (just as much as the game, which is once every three months), I'd like to touch as little of their code as possible and hopefully just have to set it up in Android. Any help or input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Lua code on Android using a library called `luaj`.

Take a look at luaj site: http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html